# Difference between pull up, pull down input high and low current

Tags: pullup, pulldown

I want to ask about the difference between the following when I was reading through a datasheet:

```
Input high current (pull-up) - Min: /; Max: 20uA
Input high current (pull-down) - Min: /; Max: 500uA
Input low current (pull-down) - Min: -20uA; Max: /
Input low current (pull-up) - Min: -500uA; Max:/
```

Can someone tell explain the difference between all fours above?.

If the target input high voltage is between 1.7-3.2V, and the voltage source is 3.3V, do I calculate the pull-up resistor value base on the Input high current (pull-up)?

Comment: Which datasheet is that from?

Answer (score -1):

The datasheets shows that if you use input high current (Pull-up) you can get a max current of 20uA and min of -20uA and the same for the three others
I hope that wil help

Comment: In that case, if I have a 3.3V supply, do I calculate like this:
1.7V < 3.3V - 20uA * R(Pull-up) < 3.2V